# How does gcc's -Wc90-c99-compat flag works?

Tags: c, gcc, c99, c89

I've a code like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
main() {
    bool ok = true;
    printf("%u\n", ok);
}
```

and I'm compiling it like

```
gcc -std=c90 -Wc90-c99-compat a.c
```

but I don't get any warnings.

I expected some kind of warning since [`bool` is not defined in C90](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/history). [The `gcc` documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) states that the `-Wc90-c99-compat` flag is used to

> [w]arn about features not present in ISO C90, but present in ISO C99.

Here you can [try it yourself](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185My85pzQlVcGmuCQlM18vw44LRSgpPz8HJJibmJmnoalQzcUJElHIz1awVSgpKk215uIsKMrMK0nTUFItjclT0gFKaVpz1f7//y85LScxvfi/LtAU22RLg/@64UBSN9nSUjc5P7cgsQQA). My version of `gcc` is 7.3.0, TIO's version is 8.1.1.

Am I doing something wrong or misunderstanding something?

Update. Something like

```
#include <stdio.h>
main() {
    _Bool ok = 1;
    printf("%u\n", ok);
}
```

does give off a warning: *warning: ISO C90 does not support boolean types*. [Try it here](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185My85pzQlVcGmuCQlM18vw44rNzEzT0NToZqLM94pPz9HIT9bwVbB0JqLs6AoM68kTUNJtTQmT0kHKK5pzVX7//@/5LScxPTi/7pAE2yTLQ3@64YDSd1kS0vd5PzcgsQSAA).

I've also tried preprocessing the first version with

```
gcc -std=c90 -Wc90-c99-compat -E a.c
```

and the relevant part becomes

```
main() {
    _Bool ok = 1;
     printf("%u\n", ok);
}
```

but no errors raised about that.

Update.

As others suggested I've filed a [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87310).

Comment: I would have expected a warning for `main()`. Does anything change if you remove `#include <stdbool.h>` and change `bool` to `_Bool`?

Comment: `main()` is used like this, without the `int` return type in C90, or at least in ANSI K&R. That's why I left it like that. And yeah, `_Bool` actually emits the warning.

Comment: Considering that `stdbool.h` just defined macros `#define true 1` and `#define bool _Bool`, I don't think it will warn about `_Bool` directly.

Comment: My guess is that the flag only warns about language features, not headers, and that `<stdbool.h>` suppresses warnings due to being a system header.

Comment: @Ivan It does warn about `_Bool` if directly used, please see the second TIO link. @melpomene Maybe, but after preprocessing the file the `bool` macro is replaced by `_Bool` so ... it's weird. Please see the updated question.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably because the macro was defined in a system header. Gcc knows where macros come from so it can suppress warnings about unportable constructs that originate from system headers.

Comment: @KohányiRóbert It might have something that suppresses this warning like `__extension__ ` keyword, although I don't remember `stdbool.h` on GCC having anything like that.

Comment: @melpomene : shouldn't [`-Wsystem-headers`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wsystem_002dheaders-365) then circumvent that suppression ? Yet it appears it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

[this is more a comment than an aswer; AFAICT this looks like a gcc bug, but someone may come with a cogent explanation of it]

Your example could be reduced to:

```
# 2 "a.c" 3
main() {
    _Bool ok = 1;
}
```

With the bug (feature?) being that `cc -std=c90 -Wc90-c99-compat -Wsystem-headers` doesn't warn about the c99 `_Bool` type, despite the `-Wsystem-headers` option.

The `3` at the end of the preprocessor line directive means that the code following it is from a system header (see the c preprocessor [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Preprocessor-Output.html)) -- and removing the `3` brings back the warning about `_Bool`.

If you check the `cc -E` output you will see that the expansions of the `bool` and `true` macros are wrapped in such lines, because they are defined in a system header (`stdbool.h`):

```
$ cat a.c
#include <stdbool.h>
main() {
    bool ok = true;
}
$ gcc -E a.c
...
main() {

# 3 "a.c" 3 4
   _Bool
# 3 "a.c"
        ok =
# 3 "a.c" 3 4
             1
# 3 "a.c"
                 ;
}
```

Comment: _[R]emoving that flag brings back the warning about `_Bool`_ Sorry I couldn't comprehend. What do you mean that? The `-Wsystem-headers` flag for me doesn't make any difference at all. Meaning the code with the `<stdbool.h>` include never produces a warning, but if I compile the `_Bool` version it always does.

Comment: removing the '3' flag from the '#' line directive/marker brings back the warning. Sorry if that wasn't clear from the context

Comment: Understood, thanks for the clarification, I've verified that this is the case. I'll file a bug about it over the `gcc` HQ somehow and get back if I learn anything.

Comment: Still, the `-Wsystem-headers` doesn't make any difference. The preprocessed output is still the same. On my end at least.

Comment: -Wsystem-headers shouldn't change the preprocessor output, it should direct the compiler to warn about dubious constructs even in system headers, and in the expansion of macros defined in the system headers. The fact that it does not warn is the bug (imo).

I'll edit out the useless flags from the "cc -E" invocation (they were an artifact of command line editing), since they seem to be the cause of the confusion.

Comment: @KohányiRóbert : when you file that bug report, can you add a link to it here for posterity ? If it's a confirmed bug, you can answer your own question with it.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Will do!